# Facebook account not accepting id upload

Tags: facebook, facebook-account

I changed the date of birth of my Facebook account because I was getting bombarded with gambling ads. So changed my age it must have been too young for Facebook as my account is gone and removed even all my posts on my girlfriends page.

The search it says I have 30 days to upload my id drivers license etc but every time I try to do that, it says

> Sorry please try again

It's been days now and I'm thinking they just removed everything so I'm sure I've lost all my photos of my kids growing up the last 12 years. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @SathyajithBhat what was so bad about my suggested edit that it was deliberately destructive? I'd like to be helpful rather than unhelpful in future. I understand looking at it again there was one typo in there but the rest of the edit does seem pretty similar to the edit you wrote yourself.

Comment: @RobertLongson I didn’t think it was bad, I could have sworn I did the “accept and improve”, not reject.. my apologies, it should not have been rejected.